# Share text, image and a hyper link Url

Tags: java, android-intent, hyperlink, share

I want to share an image with some text and a url which would deep link into my application. My url that deep links should be hyperlinked for a text eg. "here".

Below is my code

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
shareIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hey! I just saw "+res.getData().getBar_name()+"is having "+res.getData().getEvent_name()+"through the App! We should check it out.");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey! I just saw "+res.getData().getBar_name()+"is having "+res.getData().getEvent_name()+"through the App! We should check it out."
                    + "\n" + getString(R.string.webview_base)+"site/redirectlink?event_id=" + eventid);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
```

Can anyone help me with this?